# Why the console show Undefined ? ??

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, nodejs-stream

I have used **.method** to res, but the console showing me **undefined**.... Why?? help please??

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    console.log(res.method);
}).listen(9111);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have used .method to res", can you explain more, and provide additional code explaining what is method?

Answer (score 0):

The console is showing you `undefined` because there is no defined property `method` on the response object. Unlike HTTP requests, HTTP responses do not have a method type.

Perhaps you were looking for `req.method`?

Answer (score 0):

`res.method` (Response.Method) is not a property of `Response` class.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `req.method` (you are using `res.method`...) :

```
const http = require('http');

http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.method);
}).listen(9111);
```

Will print 'GET' when accessing `localhost:9111/`...

Comment: @Viking_Castle even when you change it from `res.method` to `req.method`?